# How to use the x86 Android emulator on Linux?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-sdk-2.3, android-sdk-tools

The latest Android sdk has an x86 emulator, which is supposed to help with performance.  How can I create an image for it?  When I go to make a new avd I see a dropdown for CPU/ABI but it is set to "ARM" and disabled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Step #1: Download the Intel Atom x86 System Image - API Level 10 via your SDK Manager.

Step #2: When creating an AVD, choose Intel Atom x86 System Image - API Level 10 as your target.

At the present time, the only official x86 system image is for Android 2.3.3 (a.k.a., API Level 10). There is [a third-party build of an Android 4.0.3 system image from the AOSP](http://blog.testobject.org/2012/04/giving-your-android-emulator-boost.html) that you can also install and use, though it is unofficial.

Answer (score 0):

Download and install Intel Atom x86 System image. You can use the latest version if you want.
Now follow instructions at http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html#accel-vm